# Correct way to send onPreviewFrame() byte[] with Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-camera

I'm trying to send the preview frame from a phone's camera to a tablet. In the server app I start a thread from `onPreviewFrame()` to establish a ServerSocket which in turn starts another thread that responds to button click, for verification purposes, from the client app. Like so...

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i("Server", "onPreviewFrame() called");
        mParent.new SocketServerThread(data).start();   
    }
```

where SocketServerThread does...

```
     ...
     private mData = data;
     ...
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

             while (true) {
                 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = 
                         new SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count, mData);
                 Log.i("Server", "data array sent to reply thread");
                 socketServerReplyThread.run();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

where I'm able to verify the connection via the block on `serverSocket.accept()`. The fun begins trying to deal with the data. One attempt is like so...

```
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
             DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
             dataStream.writeInt(mBuffer.length);
             if (mBuffer.length > 0)
                 outStream.write(mBuffer);
             outStream.close();

         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

I've set breakpoint and everything seems to go correctly except for `outStream.close()`'s breakpoint never gets hit. Instead it returns to my breakpoint on `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()`.

On the client side I have an `AsyncTask` that handles the connection, invoked by the onClick, like so...

```
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

     Socket socket = null;
     int bytesRead;

     try {
         socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

         InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);                     

         bytesRead = dis.read(buffer);
         if (bytesRead != -1) {
             final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

             AndroidClientActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                    //view is an ImageView
                    view.setMinimumHeight(metrics.heightPixels);
                    view.setMinimumWidth(metrics.widthPixels);
                    view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    view.refreshDrawableState();
                }
            });     
         }

     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
         if(socket != null){
             try {
                 socket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

The problem is the `ImageView` doesn't show any frames.

Question(s):

- Is there something else that needs to be done to the byte[] prior to setting the ImageView with the byte[]?
- Should the processing of the byte[] be done in the server app instead; does it matter?
- Is there an overall better approach to this?

I should mention that the previous code is a combo of some tutorials changed and meshed with my own work. I've tried achieving the same with alternate streams such as `ByteArray` and raw streams with no luck. I've found I get undependable feedback when debugging both apps at the same time and when running one while debugging the other only gives me a partial view into the problems. When I debug both I get NPEs in random places that don't occur otherwise; possibly due to pausing by the breakpoints. Not sure though.

Comment: If you want to send *video* from phone to a tablet, please consider [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming).

Comment: @AlexCohn: That's interesting; thanks. I'll have to look deeper into it over the next couple days. I intend the connection to be WifiDirect. It seems like that would be possible but the examples aren't complete; do you know off hand?

Comment: `libstreaming` examples work, but none involves WifiDirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot send raw preview frame to ImageView. ImageView is not a good choice for you, anyways, because it was not intended for dynamic (video) content.

If you want to stream video, you need to compress it on one side and decode on the other side: even WiFi does not have enough bandwidth for reasonable quality uncompressed video. Luckily, Android provides API to encode and decode video using very efficient hardware codecs.

Also, you need an advanced communication  protocol that will take care of latency, packet loss, etc. It is a big task to design and implement from scratch, even if you kiri it to bare minimum. Luckily, there is no need to reinvent this wheel. I strongly recommend the [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library which can be used for aquisition, communication, and display of live video stream.

Comment: OK. I found out fairly quickly it would be a big task. The ImageView idea came from an accepted answer to a similar question. They said it's possible to fake streaming by sending single frames and displaying them one after another. They claimed you could achieve the equivalent to about 8 fps. Thanks, now I won't waste my time attempting to finish it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use libstreaming library for a video call in a local network between two Android devices? It does not have a good document.

Comment: @HusseinYaqoobi libstreaming is unfortunately deprecated since 2018